# Why didn't Newt Scamander get a trial?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

In Fantastic Beasts, Newt is

> caught and sentenced.

Why is there no trial between

> him being sentenced to death and the attempt at execution?

Comment: Not all wizards get trials, even in the UK. If only Newt was a hypigriff, he'd have better chances getting it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The actual reason is that Graves is covering for himself, having revealed too much to Newt; a trial would lead to Newt being able to say his piece, which would inevitably expose Graves' plan:

> **Graves:** So it's [the Obscurus] useless without the host?
>
> **Newt:** "Useless?" "Useless?" That is a parasitical magical force that killed a child. What on earth would you use it for?
>
> *Newt, anger finally boiling within him, stares at Graves. Tina, reacting to the atmosphere, also looks to Graves—concern and trepidation written across her face.*
>
> *Graves realizes his mistake.*
>
> <sup>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* (2016)</sup>

His excuse is that Newt is (allegedly) trying to expose the magical world (emphasis mine):

> **Graves:** You fool nobody, Mr. Scamander. You brought this Obscurus into the city of New York in the hope of causing mass disruption — **breaking the Statute of Secrecy and revealing the magical world** -
>
> **Newt:** You know that can't hurt anyone, you know that!
>
> **Graves:** — you are therefore guilty of a treasonous betrayal of your fellow wizards and are sentenced to death.
>
> <sup>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* (2016)</sup>

Attempting to expose magical civilization is massively illegal, [especially in America](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en). Although it seems a bit of a miscarriage of justice to allow execution without trial, and things we learn later suggest that Graves is quite willing to miscarry justice, this actually seems to be standard practice in America; President Picquery later orders the execution of a citizen for much the same crime, with no evidence of a trial (emphasis mine):

> **Picquery:** The Obscurial was killed on my orders, Mr. Graves.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Picquery:** He was responsible for the death of a No-Maj. **He risked the exposure of our community. He has broken one of our most sacred laws** -
>
> <sup>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* (2016)</sup>

Although it's true that (as the OP points out in the comments on this answer) that it's rather difficult to equate the two situations, I'm sure that Graves had a suitably impressive tale in mind to tell the President.

Comment: Fair point. But death eaters get trials in other wizard of communities, such as UK. Anyway, we don't know what Graces would of really done because of of Grindleweld disguise.

Comment: @Pioneer Different jurisdictions means different laws; just because the UK commonly gives trials (even if they are just kangaroo courts) doesn't mean America will, even for similar crimes. Although, considering Newt isn't an American, the diplomatic implications of executing him are...not awesome. And yes, the Grindelwald thing is what I was (obliquely) referring to; I"ll try to make that more clear

Comment: I'm assuming that muggle commonalties between Western countries apply to Wizarding governments. However, the President had reason, it was a threat is exceptional circumstance.  Newf was in custody and secure.

Comment: The ministry officials seem perfectly fine with executing two people under G''s orders by throwing them into the veil. That is majorly weird if they're acting on their free will.

Comment: @R.Skeeter when is this?

Comment: @Pioneer - spoilers - when Tina and Newt are taken to a chamber where the veil-pool is.

Comment: @R.Skeeter then that not on the minstry orders, it on congress

Comment: @Pioneer Even if that were true (which [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_the_United_Kingdom) a [dubious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_the_United_States) assumption), why are we assuming that Graves is going to strictly follow the law?

Comment: @Pioneer Yes, I meant the MACUSA, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: "Graves is quite willing to miscarry justice, this actually seems to be standard practice in America;" cutting IRL social commentary? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## ‘Graves’ ordered the execution himself.

Newt was sentenced to be executed immediately with no delay by ‘Graves’, a respected Auror. Graves was one of the highest-level Aurors in MACUSA, so he was very trusted.

> “A group of the highest-level Aurors in the organization are gathered together in serious discussion. Among them is Graves, examining the newspaper, his face cut and bruised from last night’s encounter with the strange entity, and President Seraphina Picquery herself.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

Though it wasn’t justified and he just wanted them out of the way of his own plan, ‘Graves’ personally ordered Newt and Tina to be executed, and he specifically ordered the executioners to do it right away.

> “**GRAVES**
>   
> You fool nobody, Mr. Scamander. You brought this Obscurus into the city of New York in the hope of causing mass disruption—breaking the Statute of Secrecy and revealing the magical world—
>
> **NEWT**
>   
> You know that can’t hurt anyone, you know that!
>
> **GRAVES**
>   
> —you are therefore guilty of a treasonous betrayal of your fellow wizards and are sentenced to death. Miss Goldstein, who has aided and abetted you—
>
> **NEWT**
>   
> No, she’s done nothing of the kind—
>
> **GRAVES**
>   
> —she receives the same sentence.
>
> *The two executioners step forward. They calmly, intrusively, press the tips of their wands into Newt’s and Tina’s necks.*
>
> *Tina is so overcome with shock and fear that she can barely speak.*
>
> **GRAVES**
>   
> *(to the executioners)*
>   
> *Just do it immediately. I will inform President Picquery myself.”* 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (The Original Screenplay)n*</sup></sub>

‘Graves’ of course had ulterior motivations for his decision, but the MACUSA executioners likely considered Graves an authority to be respected, so wouldn’t have questioned his choice.